# Show that $\frac{ \sin(z) }{z(1 + z^2)} = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty (-1)^n z^{2n} \sum_{k = 0}^n \frac{1}{(2k + 1)!}$ for $|z| < 1$

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

Show that $$\frac{ \sin(z) }{z(1 + z^2)} = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty (-1)^n z^{2n} \sum_{k = 0}^n \frac{1}{(2k + 1)!}\text{ for }|z| < 1.$$

I'm doing the exercise 2.7.17 from the book Mathematical Methods in the Physical Sciences, Third Edition. I'm trying to multiply the series for $\sin(z)/z$ to the one for $(1 + z^2)^{-1}$, but i'm struggling with the change of indices. How do I obtain the upper limit $n$ for the sum on $k$?

Comment: See identity (22) in https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleSeries.html

Answer (score 0):

Let $x:=-z^2$. We need to rearrange $\prod_{i\ge0}\frac{x^i}{(2i+1)!}\prod_{j\ge0}x^j$, in which the $x^n$ coefficient is $\sum_{j=0}^n\frac{1}{(2(n-j)+1)!}$, to $\prod_{n\ge0}x^n\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{(2k+1)!}$. Just identify $k:=n-j$.